# SwiftUI : How I can delete row of ForEach in VStack?

Tags: list, swiftui, foreach, row, delete-row

This is TaskModel

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct TaskModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var title : String
    var selectedColor : Color
    var remindedTime : Int
    var taskDate : Date
}
```

This is ViewModel I tried

```
    import Foundation
    import SwiftUI
    
    class CalendarViewModel : ObservableObject {
        
        @Published var tasks : [TaskModel] = []
        @Published var currentMonth : Int = 0
        
    
        func addTask(title : String, selectedColor : Color, reminderTime : Int, taskDate : Date) {
            let newTask = TaskModel(title: title, selectedColor: selectedColor, remindedTime: reminderTime * 60, taskDate: taskDate)
            tasks.append(newTask)
        }
        
        func deleteTask(task : TaskModel) {
            if let index = tasks.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == task.id }) {
                tasks.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
```

This is the ForEach I tried to delete row

```
VStack {
                    ForEach(vm.tasks.filter({vm.isSameDay(date1: $0.taskDate, date2: currentDate)})) { task in
                        TaskRowView(task: task)
                            .actionSheet(isPresented: $isShowActionSheet) {
                                ActionSheet(title: Text("Settings"), message: Text("Press the button that what you want to do "), buttons: [
                                    .cancel(), .destructive(Text("Delete"), action: {
                                        vm.deleteTask(task: task)
                                    }), .default(Text("Edit"), action: {
                                        
                                    })
                                ])
                            }
                    }
                    
                    .onLongPressGesture {
                        isShowActionSheet.toggle()
                    }
                 }
```

And this is the picture of my app View.
[image]

The weird thing is when I tried to delete second row of the List, The first row is deleted and second is left.

But, I can't find my miss point.

Comment: It is because you use the same isShowActionSheet for all rows. When doing actionShert SwiftUI will always open action sheet for the first task.

Comment: Thank you so much! so, how I can handle that problem? could you give me one point lesson!?

Comment: @KyungyunLee: move `isShowActionSheet` and the `.actionSheet()` inside `TaskRowView()`, so that each row will have their own single sheet presented.

Comment: The only thing I see is to have an array of bool with one bool for each task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to implement this is with an optional selection variable and a custom binding for the `.actionSheet()`. Please see the code below. I commented the important parts. I also changed your code to a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for demonstration purposes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var tasks = Array(1...20).map( { TaskModel(title: "Task \($0)") })
    // This is your optional selection variable
    @State var selectedRow: TaskModel?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(tasks) { task in
                Text(task.title)
                    // put the .onLongPressGesture() on the row itself
                    .onLongPressGesture {
                        // set selectedRow to the task
                        selectedRow = task
                    }
                    // This creates a custom binding
                    .actionSheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>(
                        // the get returns the Bool that is the comparison of selectedRow and task
                        // if they are equal, the .actionSheet() fires
                        get: { selectedRow == task },
                        // when done, .actionSheet() sets the Binding<Bool> to false, but we intercept that
                        // and use it to set the selectedRow back to nil
                        set: { if !$0 {
                            selectedRow = nil
                        }})) {
                        ActionSheet(
                            title: Text("Settings"),
                            // added task.title to prove the correct row is in the ActionSheet
                            message: Text("Press the button for \(task.title)"),
                            buttons: [
                                .cancel(),
                                .destructive(Text("Delete"), action: {}),
                                .default(Text("Edit"), action: {})
                            ]
                        )
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Yrb!! But I got error like this "Operator function '==' requires that 'TaskModel' conform to 'Equatable'" at here, get: { selectedRow == task }, I can know what you are saying about it but can't know that the error is.